# Where do we purchase certificate for digital signature PDF

Tags: pdf, certificate, pdf-generation, digital-signature, tcpdf

This is an existing question only. But i dont get exact clear details on this question.

We are using TCPDF to generate PDF with signatures. And for testing purpose we have generated self signed certificate to generate signature fields and make it work.

But we want to move it to live server. So we have to suggest our client to purchase trusted certificate for this purpose.

So my question is,

What type of certificate do our client had to purchase?

Whether we can use the SSL certificate for this purpose?

If not means, where can we purchase it and what are the details do we need to know before purchase?

Please anyone provide me detail explanation on the above

Comment: That depends on the context in which your signatures shall be considered valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layman's terms, this depends on the country you are in.  There are Signature Issuing authorities, also call Certifying Authority (CA).  CA may offer various types of signature after various types of authentication method for Individuals and Corporations or Institutions.

You may search for Certifying Authority (CA) in your country and follow their procedure to get legally (binding) valid Digital Signature.

Comment: Thanks for our reply. And our client is from Australia. 1) So would this is similar to purchasing SSL certificate or is it different from that. 2) Also is the certificate is domain based. If possible can you please show any Certifying Authority (CA) in Australia

Answer (score 0):

Certificates for digital signatures are available from CAs (Certificate Authorities). Unfortunately, the CAs often charge a lot of money for such certificates.

"Code-signing" certificates won't work for digitally signing documents.

You can also get certificates for digital signatures from a couple of countries:

- [Estonia's e-residency program](https://e-resident.gov.ee/) provides a digital signing certificate on a smart card to anyone after paying €100. The cert is good for 5 years. (You don't need to open a business in Estonia, that's just what they hope you do with the card.)

  The card will be given to you at your local Estonia embassy or consulate after they verify your identity via your passport.
- [SuisseID](https://www.postsuisseid.ch/en/) -- from Switzerland, also available to anyone. Valid for 3 years, CHF 146.60 ($148)